# iron-list keep selection highlight on refresh

Tags: polymer

I am trying to keep the selected item hilighted on refresh, but I can only store it, the selection isn't rendered on refresh?

```
<iron-localstorage name="selectedItem" value="{{selectedItem}}"></iron-localstorage>
<iron-list class="flex" items="{{data}}" as="item" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selection-enabled>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm deleting all I wrong before, as it was a bit of a wild goose chase that didn't take into account a bunch of the stuff that wasn't actually being tracked in iron-list.  I've created a JSBin example here: http://jsbin.com/lataguqoge/1/edit?html

The main crux of the problem is that there are no change events tracking to the selectItem() function inside of iron-list at this moment, and the selectedItem being tracked in a object rather than an index.  Maybe, as per your Github issue, selected should be added as an index just for this reason.  As such, I'd think a more completely thought out version of this would belong in a PR to add some valuable functionality to the component.However, as you'd need to be wrapping the two of these elements in some sort of parent anyways, this isn't too too gnarly.

Here I'm catching the selectedItem change event and using the data at that point to process a selected index, which I'm saving into the iron-localstorage's value.  Then when there's something loaded out of localStorage, I use that index to selectItem() in the iron-list.

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">
    <iron-list items="{{data}}" as="item" selection-enabled on-selected-item-changed="saveSelected">
        <template>
            <div>{{item.name}}<template is="dom-if" if="{{selected}}"><span>{{index}}</span></template></div>      
        </template>
    </iron-list>
    <iron-localstorage name="ironListData" value="{{ironListData}}" on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultValue" on-iron-localstorage-load="setSelected"></iron-localstorage>
</template>
<script>
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  app.data = [
    {
      name: 'First Element'
    },
    {
      name: 'Second Element'
    },
    {
      name: 'Third Element'
    }
  ];
  app.setSelected = function(ev) {
      document.querySelector('iron-list').selectItem(app.ironListData);
  }
  app.saveSelected = function(ev) {
    if (ev.detail.value !== null)
      app.ironListData = document.querySelector('iron-list').items.indexOf(document.querySelector('iron-list').selectedItem);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok going to try that, ps what about selected-items, can that be used directly?

Comment: Hmm what kind of string does it expect? because the object just contains all the records from the row? There is no index or something, also tried setting it directly like so `selected-item="0"`

Comment: Thanks :) going to reference this to the issue